# Factory_girl simple association between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber, factory-bot, model-associations

```
FactoryGirl.define do

factory :agency do
    name "Example Inc"
    available_items "20"
    recruiter     # recruiter.id
end

factory :recruiter do
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'please'
    password_confirmation 'please'
    # required if the Devise Confirmable module is used
    # confirmed_at Time.now
end

end
```

**agency.rb**

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recruiter
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

**recruiter.rb**

```
class Recruiter < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

     # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
     attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
     attr_accessible :agency_attributes, :first_name

     has_one :agency, :dependent => :destroy

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :agency
     validates :email, :presence => true
end
```

**authentication_steps.rb**

```
def create_user
  @recruiter = FactoryGirl.create(:recruiter)
end
```

How can I replicate this Recruiter & Agency association using factory_girl?

Comment: If agency `belongs_to :recruiter` then you can only have one recruiter per agency and you've got a recruiter_id in your agencies table. Is that what you want? I'd expect to see agency `has_many :recruiters` and recruiter `belongs_to :agency`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should remove recruiter from agency factory and add agency to requiter factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :agency do 
    name "Example Inc"
    available_items "20"

    factory :agency_without_recuiter do
      recuiter_id = 1 
    end

    factory :agency_with_recuiter do
      recuiter 
    end
  end 

  factory :recuiter do
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'please'
    password_confirmation 'please'

    factory :recuiter_with_agency
      agency
    end
  end

end
```

This should work from both sides

```
create(:agency).recuiter => nil
create(:agency_with_recuiter).recuiter => recuiter

create(:recuiter).agency => nil
create(:recuiter_with_agency).agency => agency
```

Hope it will be usefull. Good luck!

Comment: If agency's have a recruiter, that means they have a recruiter_ID, and unless it's allowed to be nil, then the Agency factory should make a recruiter object so then it can point to it.

Comment: ok I understand but you dont have a validator on agency.recuiter_id. And you can set the fake recuiter_id in factory so you will have isolated agency factory. But I am not sure if is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to replicate it in your test cases, not in FG itself.

```
before (:each) do
    @recruiter = FactoryGirl.create(:recruiter)
    @agency = FactoryGirl.create(:agency)
    @agency.recruiter = @recruiter
end
```

Something like this.